# Can I alert my new users "Thanks for registering!"

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

In attempt to thank my users for registering, I found this function that redirects them to the url of my choice.

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'bryce_register_redirect');
    function bryce_register_redirect( $redirect ) {
     $redirect = 'www.myhomepage.com';
     return $redirect;
}
```

It works great, thanks http://bryceadams.com/create-woocommerce-custom-redirects/ for this awesome post.

Now That I have sent users to the page of my chosing, I would to `alert 'thanks for registering!'` or something.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'bryce_register_redirect');
function bryce_register_redirect( $redirect ) {
     $redirect = 'http://myhomepage.com';
     echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert(\'THANKS!!\'); </script>'
     return $redirect;
}
```

obviously breaks everything, because you can't just put javascript into functions.php like that.

Is there some other type of solution?

I thought that maybe I could trigger a different function after the redirect, but I am not exactly sure where to start.

Comment: Maybe show a message on the page using some dynamic html, but please don't use alert. :)

Comment: the alert was really more to help readers understand what I'm after, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Add one `div` in your home page and wrap it in a condition and condition would be something like if user is coming from the registration page(for that you can use [$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-http-referer-variable/) then show that `div` and after some timeout you can hide that `div` with jQuery or with other JS library.

Answer (score 0):

I think its

```
function bryce_register_redirect( $redirect ) {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert(\'THANKS!!\');window.location.href="'.$redirect.'"</script>';
}
bryce_register_redirect('http://myhomepage.com')
```